# retrofit post request in body with raw data

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

url=url+/api/registerotp

### I tried using this code but did not work correctly

post request in raw body data =
{"mobile_or_email": "0123456789"}

> response from server

```
{"status":true,"message":"Otp send Your Number!","otp":6425}
```

---

```
public interface Retrofit_request {
@POST("registerotp")
Call<model> getUser(@Body postd  mobile_or_email);}
```

---

```
public class model {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private Boolean status;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("otp")
@Expose
private Integer otp;

public Boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public Integer getOtp() {
    return otp;
}

public void setOtp(Integer otp) {
    this.otp = otp;
}}


 
public class RetrofitClient<minstance> {

private static final String BASE_URL=url+"/api/";
private static RetrofitClient minstance;
private Retrofit retrofit;
private RetrofitClient(){
    retrofit=new 
Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
}
public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
    if (minstance==null){
        minstance=new RetrofitClient();
    }
    return minstance;
}
public Retrofit_request getApi(){
    return retrofit.create(Retrofit_request.class);
}}
```

> main class

```
    postd postd=new postd("8273217888");
    Call<model> call = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .getUser(postd);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<model> call, Response<model> response) {
            String s = null;
            s = response.message();
            Log.d("data", s);
            Log.d("data", "true"+response);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<model> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("data t", t.getMessage());
        }
    });`
```

- 

```
public class postd {
@SerializedName("mobile_or_email")
String mobile_or_email;

public postd(String mobile_or_email) {
    this.mobile_or_email = mobile_or_email;
}

public String getMobile_or_email() {
    return mobile_or_email;
}

public void setMobile_or_email(String mobile_or_email) {
    this.mobile_or_email = mobile_or_email;
}
```

}

log-D/data: trueResponse{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https://example.com/app2/api/registerotp}

I am new to retrofit so pls tell me how to fix it

Comment: Where is the `postd` class? You need to turn the object into a JSON value before you can use it as a `@Body` parameter. Usually you'd use something like Moshi or GSON

Comment: public class postd {
    @SerializedName("mobile_or_email")
    String mobile_or_email;

    public postd(String mobile_or_email) {
        this.mobile_or_email = mobile_or_email;
    }

    public String getMobile_or_email() {
        return mobile_or_email;
    }

    public void setMobile_or_email(String mobile_or_email) {
        this.mobile_or_email = mobile_or_email;
    }
}

Comment: If you 100% sure that Body is only a set of objects, you can make it a Map<String, String>. That way you can add indivitual parameters to the body. That is only one way though, not a best practice

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: yes it will only take objects

Comment: can you pls share some link or code?

Comment: What is the expected response from the server? And what is the recieved response with that code?

Comment: it will return {"status":true,"message":"Otp send Your Number!","otp":6425}

Comment: `response.message();` is not the response, I believe it's the message of the HTTP status. `response.body()` is what you want, I believe

Comment: but it is hitting onFailure in call

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: oh sry it worked now thx man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `s = response.message();` since `response.message()` is the Response's message, not the data returned niside the response.

Use `response.body()` instead.

---

This was discussed in the comments

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onResponse(Call<model> call, Response<model> response) {
            model s = null;
            s = response.body();
            Log.d("data", s.getMessage()+""+s.getStatus()+" "+s.getOtp());

        }
```

Log:-D/data: Otp send Your Number!true 2208